# How to use "beliefern" and "liefern"?

Tags: word-usage, difference

What are the difference between *beliefern* and *liefern*? I know that both mean *to deliver* but are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 5):

"liefern" requires info on what is being delivered, optionally to whom it gets delivered to.

"beliefern" is the other way round. You must define who gets it, but it's optional to state what gets delivered.

Note Hans Peter's examples and add the example

> Wir liefern Tomaten.

for clarity of the usage.

Answer (score 4):

a) Du kannst jemanden *beliefern* (mit und genaues Objekt)

b) Du kannst etwas *liefern* (genaues Objekt)

a)    `Wir beliefern den Supermarkt schon lange`

oder

a)   `Wir beliefern den Supermarkt schon lange mit Tomaten`

b) `Wir liefern dem Supermarkt schon lange Tomaten`

Answer (score 2):

Wenn Du jemandem etwas lieferst, dann belieferst Du ihn.

Answer (score 0):

*beliefern* is the transitive version of *liefern*. The former automatically asks for an (accusative) object. It's like the difference between *antworten* und *beantworten*:

> antworten auf die Frage = die Frage beantworten